# Create a new row for each new record in js

Tags: javascript

I have to following code where the user enter two field values and then click on the button that copy (and combine) the values of the two fields and write them to one text box. Each time new values are typed and the button clicked, it is added to the Field3 text box. I want the records to write each one to its own row.

At the moment records are displayed as:

```
abc - def ghi - jkl
```

instead of

```
abc - def
ghi - jkl
```

My code is:

```
<html> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function copy()

{ 
    var field1 = document.getElementById("Field1"); 
    var field2 = document.getElementById("Field2"); 
    var field3 = document.getElementById("Field3");
    Field2.value = Field2.value + Field1.value + " - " + Field3.value;
    Field1.value = ''
    Field3.value = ''
 } 
</script> 
<input type="button" value="Add Qualification" onClick="copy();" /> 
</html>
```

Help would be appreciated as I am new to JS

Thanks

Marius

Comment: What about `Field2.value = Field2.value + "\n" + Field1.value + " - " + Field3.value;`?

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha Post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**What is \n and \r ?**

- \n is used as an end-of-line terminator in Unix text files
- \r is used as an end-of-line terminator in Mac text files
- \r\n (ie both) are used to terminate lines in Windows and DOS text
  files.

so you know how to break the end of line by now so you can change your code to break the line after the first input :

```
<html> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function copy()

{ 
    var field1 = document.getElementById("Field1"); 
    var field2 = document.getElementById("Field2"); 
    var field3 = document.getElementById("Field3");
    Field2.value = Field2.value + "\n\r" + Field1.value + " - " + Field3.value;
    Field1.value = ''
    Field3.value = ''
 } 
</script> 
<input type="button" value="Add Qualification" onClick="copy();" /> 
</html>
```

and hey! you can use string interpolation too. its new in ES6 and its so cool.

[here you can read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

and by that, your code would looks like this

```
<html> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function copy()

{ 
    var field1 = document.getElementById("Field1"); 
    var field2 = document.getElementById("Field2"); 
    var field3 = document.getElementById("Field3");
    Field2.value = `${Field2.value}\n\r${Field1.value}-${Field3.value}`;
    Field1.value = ''
    Field3.value = ''
 } 
</script> 
<input type="button" value="Add Qualification" onClick="copy();" /> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much appreciated

Comment: @MariusRoos consider mark my answer as the final answer if it fixes the problem.